# Aligning the start of a hairpin at the start of a bar despite acciaccatura

Tags: lilypond

I'd like to get a hairpin to start at the beginning of a bar, when the bar begins with an acciaccatura, and I'm not having any luck.

This is what I want:

[image: Goal]

Here's what I've got instead:

[image: What I've got]

```
\version "2.18.2"
\language "english"
dynamics = {
 s2. |
 s8 \> s4 s4 s8 \!
}
\score {
  \relative c'' {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff { \time 3/4 c4 e g | \acciaccatura{g,16 a} g8 a4 d f8 }
    \new Dynamics = "dynamics" \dynamics
    \new Staff { \clef "bass" c,,4 c' e | c e, g}
  >>
  }
  \layout { }
}
```

I got the target image by ditching the dynamics staff and putting the hairpin directly into the treble staff, with the `\>` inside of the `\acciaccatura{...}`. I'd like to keep all of the dynamics markings in the `dynamics` staff if possible.

Comment: If the dynamics staff thing is a bad idea for a long complicated piano piece, I'm open to comments on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dynamics staff thing is a *good* idea. Your problem is very simple: you put the hairpin at the first beat of the bar, but you need to put it "an 8th grace note *before*" that. Instead of

```
s8 \> s4 s4 s8 \!
```

just write

```
\grace{s16\> s} s8 s4 s s8\!
```

And, by the way, it's not needed to copy any particular rhythm with the contents of your `Dynamics`. So you can just write

```
\grace{s8\>} s2 s8 s\!
```

You can also play with it in a [lilybin](http://lilybin.com/uqewvn/2).

Comment: Ah! That's so simple! Thanks. Glad to hear I'm on track with the dynamics thing.